# How to do the "inverse" of `git rebase <some-branch>`?

Tags: git, git-rebase

In the history below, assume that commits `B` through `E` are completely independent from commits `F` through `I`.

```
                       br-1            master
  ⋯ ---A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I
```

How do I end up with a history that looks like this:

```
                       master
  ⋯ ---A---F'--G'--H'--I'
        \
         `-B---C---D---E
                       br-1
```

?

`br-1` and `master` are meant to be branches.  The prime in `F'` is meant to indicate that *commit* `F'` *consists of exactly the same changes as those that went into commit* `F`.  Similarly for `G'`, `H'`, and `I'`.

(The desired operation is, effectively, the inverse of doing `git rebase br-1` from `master`, starting from the second history shown above.)

Comment: That's not really a rebase in reverse. It's just a rebase.

Comment: @Chris: You are technically correct, but the question title is perfectly chosen for Git beginners, because the usual operation is to put a branch at the top of another - and this is the inverse operation: Putting that part back at the root of a branch.

Comment: @Chris: IMO, `git` terminology/nomenclature is so screwed up that it is pointless to quibble over what is "really" what.  E.g. a `git` "branch" is not a branch in any sense known outside of `git`.  Or, with an "interactive rebase" one can do things that no one outside of `git` would ever describe as "rebasing" anything.  This list of crazy "`git`-only" terminology could go on.  (BTW, this is, IMO, one of the reasons for why learning `git` is so difficult, something I'm reminded of every time I see the insane vote counts of the "Related" `git` questions that SO throws in its right-side column.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `master` checked out:

```
git rebase --onto A br-1 master
```

Answer (score 7):

Two options.

1)

```
git checkout master
git rebase --interactive A
```

Delete the lines for B through E

2)

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto A E
```

Comment: I want to thank you explicitly for your answer (since I ended up accepting the one that appeared first).  In particular, I found your first option instructive.  Now I realize that it's one I should have been able to come up with myself (and wish I had).